# explode / implode string from "HH,K3,AB,EH" into "'HH', 'K3', 'AB', 'EH'" for mysql order by field

Tags: php

I have a string variable like `HH,K3,AB,EH`

I need to sort a mysql query with it and need to chance it into

```
SELECT grouptyp, groupname,
       FIELD(grouptyp, **'HH', 'K3', 'AB', 'EH'**) as ordergrouptyp
FROM groups
ORDER BY ordergrouptyp
```

Any better way than to explode and implode the string?

Can I implode the string with apostrophe for the mysql-query?

```
$str = "HH,K3,AB,EH";
$arr = explode(" ",$str);
$newstr = "'" . implode("', '",$arr) . "'";
```

Thanks

Comment: `$str` has no spaces so you can't explode on that character. If you explode on the `,` I think you will get what you want. https://eval.in/721374.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you explode with "," i think that will do it.

```
$str = "HH,K3,AB,EH";
$arr = explode(",",$str);
$newstr = "'" . implode("', '",$arr) . "'";
```